# Como usar o jqZoom em uma imagem base64?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, imagem, base64

**Situação:**

Tenho uma pequena aplicação onde o usuário escolhe uma opção do `<select>` e nisso uma imagem é carregada via [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) utilizando [base64](/questions/tagged/base64).

**Problema:**

O plugin jqZoom não funciona corretamente com imagens [base64](/questions/tagged/base64) pois ele congela e não consegue se mover.

**Observação:**

Realizei testes com uma imagem que estava no diretório da aplicação utilizando caminho relativo e o jqZoom estava normal, ou seja, não sendo uma imagem [base64](/questions/tagged/base64) funciona.

**Objetivo:**

Gostaria de saber como devo proceder para que o plugin funcione com [base64](/questions/tagged/base64) ou gostaria de saber alguma outra forma de obter meu resultado que seria um zoom na imagem base64 carregada via XHR no [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), se for o caso de utilizar outro plugin de zoom, também posso fazer.

Comment: Você poderia incluir um exemplo curto e funcional pra gente ver o problema ocorrendo e tentar ajudar a resolver? Obrigado!

Comment: Achou alguma solução? Poste como resposta para ajudar outras pessoas.

Comment: infelizmente não achei nenhuma solução :(